# How to stop TFS build if test fails?

Tags: automated-tests, tfsbuild

How to stop TFS 2013 build if a smoke test fails?

E.g. I have 2 sets of tests: smoke and regression. I want make TFS Build stop if smoke tests failed.

Is there a parameter for this?

Thanks.